# Drawing graphics part by part

Tags: graphics, optics

What I want to do is to draw graphics part by part, because I made a function that generates coordinates according to which I will draw graphics. The problem is that MMA does not operate as I expected. To figure out what I'm doing here's simplified example:

```
Graphics[{
  a = 1;
  Label[tag];
  If[a < 3,
   {Circle[{a, 1}, 1],
    a = a + 1;
    Goto[tag];},
   {Text["It's finished", {0, 0}]}]
  }]
```

And what I get as output is simply text "It's finished". But what I want as output is graphics with two circles with radii 1 and centers positioned at {1,1} and {2,1} together with text "It's finished".

I figure out the way MMA thinks, and why it gives me this as output. But how can I accomplish my desired output?

**Edit:**

Here's the code, It's really messy and tips on how to neatly write code in MMA would be appreciated.

```
   Manipulate[

    Graphics[{

    (*calculating incident angle*)
    α = ArcSin[H/R];
    (*calculating x-coordinate where incident ray leaves prism*)
    p = Sqrt[R^2 - H^2];
    (*Drawing incident ray*)
    {Red, Thick, Line[{{-2, H}, {p, H}}]},

    (*Drawing prism*)
    {Blue, Opacity[.5], Disk[{0, 0}, R, {0, Pi/2}]},

    (*checking whether it's reflection or refraction*)
    If[H < R/n,
            {(*refraction*)
            (*calculating x-coordinate where refracted ray hits surface*)
            l = (R^2 n)/(Sqrt[R^2 - H^2] n - Sqrt[R^2 - H^2 n^2]);
            (*Drawing refracted ray*)
            {Red, Thick, Line[{{p, H}, {l, 0}}]}
            },

    {(*internal reflection*)
                (*calculating x-coordinate where after internal reflection ray hits \
surface*)
                new = H;
                k = 1;
            Label[tag];
            s = R Cos[α] - new/Tan[2 α];
                If[s <= R,
                {
                {Red, Thick, Line[{{p, new}, {s, 0}}]}
                },

                  {
                θ = (2 k + 1) α - k Pi;
                f = R Cos[θ];
                h = R Sin[θ];
                k = k + 1;
                Line[{{{p, new}, {f, h}}}],
                new = h;
                p = f;
                Goto[tag];
                }
                ]
            }
        ]
            }],

    {{H, 3, "Height"}, 0.0001, R - 0.0001, Appearance -> "Labeled"},
    {{n, 1.5, "Refraction"}, 1.001, 2, Appearance -> "Labeled"},
    {{R, 10, "Radius"}, 0, 10, Appearance -> "Labeled"}
            ]
```

Comment: I think you need to reconstruct this using either [While](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/While.html) or [TakeWhile](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/TakeWhile.html)

Comment: Do you really want to do this with `Goto`? It'll be more complicated than what I gave below.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you want is done by

```
Graphics[Table[Circle[{a, 1}, 1], {a, 1, 2}] ~Append~ Text["It's finished", {0, 0}]]
```

[image]

Here's another approach, with minimal changes to your code:

```
Graphics[
  {
     a = 1;
     Label[tag];
     If[a < 3,
        {Sow @ Circle[{a, 1}, 1], a = a + 1; Goto[tag];},
        {Sow @ Text["It's finished", {0, 0}]}]
  } // Reap // Last // Last
]
```

EDIT: I'm afraid I am not sure what that is supposed to look like, but does this

```
Manipulate[
 Graphics[
  {
   α = ArcSin[H/R];
   p = Sqrt[R^2 - H^2];
   {Red, Thick, Line[{{-2, H}, {p, H}}]},
   {Blue, Opacity[.5], Disk[{0, 0}, R, {0, Pi/2}]},
   If[
    H < R/n,
    {
     l = (R^2 n)/(Sqrt[R^2 - H^2] n - Sqrt[R^2 - H^2 n^2]);
     {Red, Thick, Line[{{p, H}, {l, 0}}]}
     },
    Last@Last@Reap[
       {
        novo = H;
        k = 2;
        Sow@Text[θ, {10, 5}], Text[α, {10, 7}], 
        Text[k, {10, 9}],
        Label[oznaka];
        s = R Cos[α] - novo/Tan[2 α];
        If[s <= R,
         Sow@{{Red, Thick, Line[{{p, novo}, {s, 0}}]}},
         {θ = (2 k + 1) α - k Pi;
          f = R Cos[θ];
          h = R Sin[θ];
          k = k + 1;
          Sow@Line[{{{p, novo}, {f, h}}}], novo = h;
          p = f;
          Goto[oznaka];}]}
       ]
    ]
   }
  ],
 {{H, 9.45991`, "Vertikalna udaljenost upadne zrake"}, 0.0001, 
  R - 0.0001, 
  Appearance -> "Labeled"}, {{n, 1.5, 
   "Koeficijent prelamanja stakla"}, 1.001, 2, 
  Appearance -> "Labeled"}, {{R, 10, "Poluprecnik prizme"}, 0, 10, 
  Appearance -> "Labeled"}]
```

work?

[image]

Comment: I don't think that Table[] will help me, because I have complicated graphics. But it's my fault, I did't explained it in my question, I'll edit it now.

Comment: This is a minimally-altered version of your code that (I think) does what you want. Are you sure `Table` won't work? It's practically equivalent to the `If`-`Goto` structure you have.

Comment: @balboa: maybe you should be asking about your "complicated graphics" instead of this toy example...

Comment: I put that "complicated graphics" in edit, but I'll try to implement show, maybe that would work.

Comment: yes, you solved it, I don't know how because I rushed with question and code I put was bad. But you did it. Thank you very much. And sorry for bad asked question.

Comment: No problem. I will try to make some suggestions on how to make this more readable/less error prone tomorrow (although this is the first time I've seen `Goto` used in mathematica, which makes this exotic...)

Comment: then see the edits that I made in question, I translated the comments, and fixed few minor mistakes. Also when looking at your answer I noticed that I have some bugs in my code (I think I made mistakes in calculating angle). Anyway it's too late, I'll focus on that tomorrow. Once again thank you, as well all others on effort :)

Answer (score 2):

(Starting remark: Just like in any other language, `Goto` is an evil statement that should never ever be used.)

One way of accomplishing what you want is generating the code as an ordinary list, and then giving this to `Graphics`:

```
 In[1] := circles = Table[Circle[{a, 1}], {a, 1, 2}]
Out[1]  = {Circle[{1, 1}], Circle[{2, 1}]}

 In[2] := text = {Text["It's finished", {0, 0}]}
Out[2]  = {Text["It's finished", {0, 0}]}

 In[3] := Join[circles, text]
          Graphics[%]
Out[3]  = {Circle[{1, 1}], Circle[{2, 1}], Text["It's finished", {0, 0}]}
```

[image]

You could also have created two separate graphics first, and then combined these with `Show`:

```
circles = Graphics@Table[Circle[{a, 1}], {a, 1, 2}];
text = Graphics@{Text["It's finished", {0, 0}]};
Show[circles, text]
```

Comment: "`Goto[]` is an evil statement that should never ever be used." - that's quite harsh; there are times one might need to use a label-goto pair. On the other hand, due to the richness of *Mathematica*, times like those are exceedingly rare.

Answer (score 1):

If you know for sure that it is just a matter of $a = 1, 2, 3,...$ and you want to stop at 3, then this is sufficient.

```
Graphics[Join[
 Circle[{#, 1}, 1] & /@ Range[3], {Text["It's finished", {0, 0}]}]]
```

If the values of $a$ are not known in advance and not in order of magnitude, then something like this would be sufficient:

```
Graphics[Join[
 Circle[{#, 1}, 1] & /@ 
  TakeWhile[RandomInteger[4, {10}], # < 4 &], {Text["It's finished", {0, 0}]}]]
```

Note I've used $a<4$ as the criterion not $a<3$ as in the question, to make the second example a bit more interesting. Both cases generate a graphic identical to this one.

[image]

But from the title of your question, I get the impression that what you really want is a sequence of graphics, showing the image built up step by step. For that you want something using `NestWhileList`, `FoldList` or similar. Below is an example using `NestWhileList`. If you only want the last one to have the text, this is a straightforward modification of the code below.

```
Graphics[Join[#, {Text["It's finished", {0, 0}]}]] & /@ 
Rest@NestWhileList[
Flatten@Join[{#}, {Circle[{Length[#] + 1, 1}, 1]}] &, {}, 
Length[#] < 3 &]
```

[image]